# Firebug "whitelist" mode

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox-addon

How do I get Firebug to do this:

(from the Firebug website http://getfirebug.com/using.html)
You can browse in two modes - either enable Firebug for all websites except those on the "blacklist", or disable Firebug for all websites except those on the "whitelist".

How do I get the second option? I don't want Firebug running for every site I visit, just those I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose 'Disabled' from the Console dropdown (this disables all by default), then click the 'Sites' item from the same dropdown. A dialog will pop up where you can select which sites to enable Firebug (the whitelist).